How to determine if a face intersects with other faces
I am using Python scripts for filling, and sometimes he may encounter situations as shown in the picture

the fill face intersects with the pre-existing face
This is obviously not good, so is there an API that can determine whether a certain face intersects with other faces?

You can activate the addon called 3D-Print Tools, then in the N panel > 3D-Print, click on Check All and it will tell you how many faces intersect, and in Edit mode if you click on the Intersect Face it will show you the faces, under Clean Up you can click on Make Manifold and see what it give. Also with the Voxel remesh you can get rid of bad topology but it will change the shape a bit and you may not want that
